# Code coverage is not displayed when viewed from generated folder but shown in terminal

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, specs

Any idea why code coverage in specific percentages is not shown when viewing from generated coverage folder but it is visible in terminal. Please find attachments below for the issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image: js]

Comment: how did you setup the path?

Comment: This is really strange. Did you change anything in karma.conf.js ?

Comment: No.. i havent chnaged anything. I have also compared karma.conf.js with other angular project which is wroking fine, there is no change

Comment: This issue already seems to be reported and resolved. Please visit :: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9388

Comment: @Sajeetharan, which path you mean? in karma.conf.js file i have this -> dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/cicd-ui'),

Comment: I beleive you'll need to update to latest version of the coverage reporter

Comment: "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0" These are the versions used.. I think these are latest

Comment: No they aren't... for eg. Latest version of karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter is 3.0.3 but not 2.0.1 This is just an example.. please try to find out the version info in npmjs.com

Comment: I have changed karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter version to 3.0.3, it is working now. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

updated version of "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter" to "3.0.3", resolved issue.